# How to declare application class properly in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have declared and defined the code, If I run in debug mode. My debugger never comes to that point

**manifest declaration:**

```
 <application
            android:name=".application.CaringApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"/>
```

**CaringApplication.kt**

```
class CaringApplication : Application() {

    val TAG = CaringApplication::class.java!!.simpleName

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
    }
}
```

`CaringApplication` is not reachable

Comment: never comes to what point? Did you set a breakpoint? Where?

Comment: @TimCastelijns ....   break point at `Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())`

Comment: CaringApplication  and manifest has same package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing just the class name, write the entire package path 
for eg `com.packageName.subPackageName.class` in the manifest.
Once written,press Ctrl+leftClick on class name , it should re-direct you to your respective Application class.

Comment: Sorry,but working(Kotlin) on my side,De-Bugging with break-points might help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your package name is correct when you add `android:name` value

Make sure also that your build complete successfully without any problem

Try to invalidate the cache and restart

Comment: No there is no changes try to comment this line ` Fabric.with(this,Crashlytics())`
and break point at ` super.onCreate()`